# Is there a way to use DISTINCT and COUNT(*) together to bulletproof your code against DUPLICATE entries?

Tags: sql, ssms, aggregate-functions

I got help with a function yesterday to correctly get the count of multiple items in a column based on multiple criteria/columns. However, if there is a way to get the DISTINCT count of all the entries in the table based on aggregated GROUP BY statement.

```
    SELECT      TIME = ap.day,
                acms.tenantId,
                acms.CallingService,
                policyList = ltrim(sp.value),
                policyInstanceList = ltrim(dp.value),
                COUNT(*) AS DISTINCTCount
    FROM        dbo.acms_data acms
    CROSS APPLY string_split(acms.policyList, ',') sp
    CROSS APPLY string_split(acms.policyInstanceList, ',') dp
    CROSS APPLY (select day = convert(date, acms.[Time])) ap
    GROUP BY    ap.day, acms.tenantId, sp.value, dp.value, acms.CallingService
```

I would just like to know if there would be a way to see if there is a workaround for using DISTINCT and Count(*) together and whether or not it would affect my results to make this algorithm potentially invulnerable to duplicate entries.

The reason why I have to use COUNT(*) is because I am aggregating based on every column in the table not just a specific column or multiple.

Comment: I can't give you a direct answer because you aren't qualifying what counts as distinct. If you have specific logic for dictating what is unique or not, that is what a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` is for, as it will both enforce the uniqueness of data, and provide lookup index to facilitate this table constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use DISTINCT with COUNT together like this example.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO
-- This query shows 290 JobTitle 
SELECT COUNT(JobTitle) Total_JobTitle 
FROM [HumanResources].[Employee]
GO
-- This query shows only 67 JobTitle 
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT JobTitle) Total_Distinct_JobTitle
FROM [HumanResources].[Employee]
GO
```

[image]